# skipping http protocol in url doesn't load the script file

Tags: javascript, src

I open my index.html in browser as `file:///` and the scripts with no protocol name are not loaded.

```
<script type="text/javascript" language="javascript" src="//code.jquery.com/jquery-1.10.2.min.js"></script>
```

This doesn't work in mozilla 36.0.4, chrome on my machine.

On using `node-static` server, the jquery file gets loaded successfully.

Can we skip the protocol names in `script` links and still open the file as `file:///`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No, you will need to edit the index.html files and add 'http' or 'https' to the script tags.

Skipping the protocol means using the same protocol as the page was loaded with (which is useful for instance if you allow both http and https). But in this case the browser would interpret the above as:

```
<script type="text/javascript" language="javascript" src="file:///code.jquery.com/jquery-1.10.2.min.js"></script>
```

Answer (score 0):

You should edit (add `http` )

`<script type="text/javascript" language="javascript" src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.10.2.min.js"></script>`

Because // not work when it not apache or iis.